# Завершение приложения после закрытия основного окна

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Как закрыть все окна и завершить приложение после закрытия основного окна?

Проблема в том, что если будет открыто второе окно, а главное закроется приложение будет работать с открытым вторым окном. 
Как это исправить?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Car:
    color = "red"
    year = 215


class Form(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent
    
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.setStyleSheet(f"QMainWindow {{background-color: {self.parent.car.color};}}")
        
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Поменять color')
        self.btnMain = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Окно main')
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn, 0, 0)                  
        layout.addWidget(self.btnMain, 1, 0)
        
        self.add_function()
        
    def add_function(self):
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.changeColorBlack)
        self.btnMain.clicked.connect(self.openMain)
        
    def changeColorBlack(self):
        self.parent.car.color = "blue"
        self.setStyleSheet(f"QMainWindow {{background-color: {self.parent.car.color};}}")

    def openMain(self):       
        self.parent.setStyleSheet(f"QMainWindow {{background-color: {self.parent.car.color};}}")
        self.parent.show()
        #self.close()
        

# Как из этого класса обращаться к объекту volvo?
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Поменять color')
        self.btnForm = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Окно Form')
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn, 0, 0)                
        layout.addWidget(self.btnForm, 1, 0)
        
        self.car = Car()
        self.setStyleSheet(f"QMainWindow {{background-color: {self.car.color};}}")
        
        self.add_function()
        
    def add_function(self):
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.changeColorWhite)
        self.btnForm.clicked.connect(self.openForm)
        
    def changeColorWhite(self):
        #Как из этой функции обращаться к объекту volvo?
#        self.volvo.color = "white"
        self.car.color = "yellow"
        self.setStyleSheet(f"QMainWindow {{background-color: {self.car.color};}}")
       
    def openForm(self):       
        self.form = Form(self)
        self.form.setWindowTitle("Hello Form.")
        self.form.show()
        #self.hide()
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle("Hello World!!")
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хотя я не понимаю, что вас смущает в моем первом ответе, предложу вам другой вариант, который сделает то же самое.

Переопределите метод `closeEvent`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Car:
    color = "red"
    year = 215


class Form(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__() 
        self.parent = parent
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Hello Form!")
    
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.setStyleSheet(f"QMainWindow {{background-color: {self.parent.car.color};}}")
        
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Поменять color')
        self.btnMain = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Окно main')
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn, 0, 0)                  
        layout.addWidget(self.btnMain, 1, 0)
        
        self.add_function()
        
    def add_function(self):
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.changeColorBlack)
        self.btnMain.clicked.connect(self.openMain)
        
    def changeColorBlack(self):
        self.parent.car.color = "blue"
        self.setStyleSheet(f"QMainWindow {{background-color: {self.parent.car.color};}}")

    def openMain(self):       
        self.parent.setStyleSheet(f"QMainWindow {{background-color: {self.parent.car.color};}}")
        self.parent.show()
        #self.close()
        

# Как из этого класса обращаться к объекту volvo?
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Поменять color')
        self.btnForm = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Окно Form')
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn, 0, 0)                
        layout.addWidget(self.btnForm, 1, 0)
        
        self.car = Car()
        self.setStyleSheet(f"QMainWindow {{background-color: {self.car.color};}}")
        
        self.add_function()
        
    def add_function(self):
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.changeColorWhite)
        self.btnForm.clicked.connect(self.openForm)
        
    def changeColorWhite(self):
        #Как из этой функции обращаться к объекту volvo?
#        self.volvo.color = "white"
        self.car.color = "yellow"
        self.setStyleSheet(f"QMainWindow {{background-color: {self.car.color};}}")
       
    def openForm(self):       
        self.form = Form(self)
        self.form.setWindowTitle("Hello Form.")
        self.form.show()
        #self.hide()
        
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Информация',
            "Вы хотите закрыть все окна?",
             QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes,
             QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.form.close()
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle("Hello World!!")
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В данном примере это все работает, но когда у каждой формы есть дочерний класс и мы ими оперируем не первый не второй вариант не работает =(
постараюсь минимальный пример кода привести в обновлении

Comment: @helldrg я вам предложил два возможных варианта решения согласно вашего примера. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour  Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос, приведите пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Класс `Form` инициализируйте так:

```
...
super().__init__(parent)      # <--- parent
...
```

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Car:
    color = "red"
    year = 215


class Form(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)                               # <--- parent
        self.parent = parent
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Hello Form!")
    
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.setStyleSheet(f"QMainWindow {{background-color: {self.parent.car.color};}}")
        
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Поменять color')
        self.btnMain = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Окно main')
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn, 0, 0)                  
        layout.addWidget(self.btnMain, 1, 0)
        
        self.add_function()
        
    def add_function(self):
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.changeColorBlack)
        self.btnMain.clicked.connect(self.openMain)
        
    def changeColorBlack(self):
        self.parent.car.color = "blue"
        self.setStyleSheet(f"QMainWindow {{background-color: {self.parent.car.color};}}")

    def openMain(self):       
        self.parent.setStyleSheet(f"QMainWindow {{background-color: {self.parent.car.color};}}")
        self.parent.show()
        #self.close()
        

# Как из этого класса обращаться к объекту volvo?
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Поменять color')
        self.btnForm = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Окно Form')
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn, 0, 0)                
        layout.addWidget(self.btnForm, 1, 0)
        
        self.car = Car()
        self.setStyleSheet(f"QMainWindow {{background-color: {self.car.color};}}")
        
        self.add_function()
        
    def add_function(self):
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.changeColorWhite)
        self.btnForm.clicked.connect(self.openForm)
        
    def changeColorWhite(self):
        #Как из этой функции обращаться к объекту volvo?
#        self.volvo.color = "white"
        self.car.color = "yellow"
        self.setStyleSheet(f"QMainWindow {{background-color: {self.car.color};}}")
       
    def openForm(self):       
        self.form = Form(self)
        self.form.setWindowTitle("Hello Form.")
        self.form.show()
        #self.hide()
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle("Hello World!!")
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мы просто добавляем ссылку на родительский класс?

Comment: @helldrg по сути, да

Comment: @helldrg что не так?